# How to change programmatically a global setting like 'haptic feedback'?

Tags: android

How can I change programmatically a global setting like 'haptic feedback'?
(Manually you can change this setting in 'Sound & Display Settings')

Changing e.g. the airplane mode can be done with the following code:

```
private void setAirplaneMode(boolean bOn)
{
    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), 
                           Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 
                           bOn ? 1 : 0); 

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
    intent.putExtra("state", bOn ? 1 : 0);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

However, for 'haptic feedback' this does not work because I don't find a corresponding intent.

Simply

```
private void setHapticFeedbackMode(boolean bOn)
{
     Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                            Settings.System.HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED, 
                            bOn ? 1 : 0);
}
```

does not work (I guess a broadcast of an intent is really necessary).

I am not interested in things like `setHapticFeedbackEnabled`, because in that way you are only changing the way how the calling app/view is handling haptic feedback.
I am looking for a way to change the global setting. (Like if you were checking/unchecking the checkbox in 'Sound & Display Settings' manually.)

Answer (score 6):

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED, 0);
```

This does work for me. You have set the `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission in your manifest I assume.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `VIBRATE_SETTING_CHANGED` or `RINGER_MODE_CHANGED`? These are provided in the broadcast intent list under SDK's `platforms/android-x/data/broadcast_actions.txt`.

Comment: Dear, yes I have tried those ones, but without success. But I should say that it is not very clear to me which "putExtra" arguments that I should add to VIBRATE_SETTING_CHANGED and RINGER_MODE_CHANGED. Where could I find information with which I could know which arguments belong to them (and other intents)?

Comment: The list of all the constants is here (if that's what you're asking about): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html. So, for example, ringer mode constants are `RINGER_MODE_NORMAL`, `RINGER_MODE_SILENT` and `RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE`.