# How to change Screen Lock sounds settings programmatically on Android

Tags: android, settings, screen-lock

How to change Screen Lock sounds settings (from Settings->Sounds->screen lock sounds) checkbox programmatically on Android?

For example if I want to change haptic feedback setting i'll do:

```
Settings.System.putInt(m_context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED, bEnable ? 1 : 0);
```

What define for Screen Lock Sounds?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696934/how-to-change-programmatically-a-global-setting-like-haptic-feedback

Comment: Are you sure? If so, please tell me the constant name for this? I know to change the most settings from sounds, except this. So, please tell me the constant name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Android Source code its constant is "LOCKSCREEN_SOUNDS_ENABLED"

http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/SoundSettings.java#301

Comment: thamks, it's help a lot. however this define is not present in Settings.System. I found the string associated with this constant. So the solution will be: Settings.System.putInt(m_context.getContentResolver(), "lockscreen_sounds_enabled" , bEnable ? 1 : 0);